# How to span belongs_to and has_many relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have the models below:

```
class Origtext < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book, :chapter, :textual, :verse
  has_many :reviews
end


class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origtext
  attr_accessible :description
end
```

The below collects all origtexts where the book is 'Bible'

```
@origtexts = Origtext.where(:book => 'Bible')
```

What is the ruby code for how to collect all reviews associated with a certain book?

Posting code to iterate through reviews:

```
# @reviews.each do |review|
    #   puts review
    # end
```

Comment: Do you want all reviews for this specific book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your console:

```
@origtexts = Origtext.where(:book => 'Bible')

@origtexts.each do |orig_text|
  puts orig_text.name
  puts orig_text.reviews # puts the reviews associated with the orig_text
end
```

Or with an id:

```
@origtext = Origtext.where(id: params[:id]).first
@origtext.reviews # returns the reviews associated with the origtext
```

Or directly from the Review model:

```
the_holy_bible = Origtext.where(:book => 'Bible').first
@reviews = Review.where(origtext_id: the_holy_bible.id)
```

Comment: I have multiple entries under Origtext that have the 'Bible' attribute for book.  I'm finding that the last 2 methods only return 1 review each time even though I have multiple reviews that each have the 'Bible' attribute in Origtexts.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as straightforward as the following:

```
@reviews = @origtexts.each(&:reviews)
```

Comment: When I try to iterate through @reviews I get an error saying undefined method `description'

Comment: Does your Review table have a `description` column?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it does.  It's in the review.rb file.  I'm also seeing the data in SQL Lite viewer and see a column named description.

Comment: Could you please post the code you've used to iterate through the reviews?

Answer (score 0):

```
@reviews = Review.where(:origtext => { :book => 'Bible' })
```

Comment: I tried to iterate through this with...@reviews.each do |review|
 puts review.description
end...and I get an error saying no such column.

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: origtext.book: SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews"  WHERE "origtext"."book" = 'Bible'